# Strange behaviour of grep command

Tags: grep

When I do the following grep I get results I cannot explain to myself:

```
host:/usr/local/tomcat > grep '-XX:PermSize=256m' *
RELEASE-NOTES:      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
RUNNING.txt:      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
```

Afaik, none of the characters in my regular expression have a special meaning (inside square brackets, `-` has one, but there are none). I also put it into single quotes so it shouldn’t be modified by the shell.

- Grep version: grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1
- Tomcat version: 6.0.36 (binary
  distro)

Answer (score 4):

Since your pattern begins with a minus sign `-`, `grep` interprets it as an argument.

You could say:

```
grep -- '-XX:PermSize=256m' *
```

`--` would tell `grep` to stop processing command line arguments.

Alternatively, you could say:

```
grep -- '[-]XX:PermSize=256m' *
```

---

(When you say `[-]` the hyphen is interpreted as a literal.  Since you say `(inside square brackets, - has one..`, it seemed that it should be clarified.)

Answer (score 3):

The shell expands the command to the following:

```
grep -XX:PermSize=256m LICENSE NOTICE RELEASE-NOTES RUNNING.txt bin conf lib …
```

Grep accepts a secret parameter `-Xoptarg` without reporting an *invalid option*. [In the source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/src/main.c#n1550) it reads

```
  /* -X is undocumented on purpose. */
```

However, the next token, `LICENSE` is taken as regular expression. Typing `grep -X *` takes the LICENSE token as input string to the parameter `-X` and greps for *NOTICE* in RELEASE-NOTES and RUNNING.txt.

The meaning of the secret grep capital X parameter is to set the internal mode, i.e.

- `grep -X grep` → behave normally (`grep -G`)
- `grep -X egrep` → behave like `grep -E`
- `grep -X awk` → uses [`RE_SYNTAX_AWK`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/src/grep.c#n19)
- `grep -X fgrep` → behave like `grep -F`
- `grep -X perl` → behave like `grep -P`
- `grep -X 'unrecognized string'` → behave normally

Comment: +1 for the link to the [source](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/src/main.c#n1550).

Answer (score 2):

My `grep` complains about

```
grep: invalid matcher X:PermSize=256m
```

but what you can see here is that `grep` considers `-X...` as an option. To make it stop interpreting options, use `--`, i.e.

```
grep -- -XX:PermSize=256m *
```

The single-quotes are not necessary.